# Reset Azure B2C Password using MS Graph from Logic Apps

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-logic-apps, aad-b2c

I am using a Logic App to automate creation of new users and update attributes in a Azure B2C Tenant. It works perfectly for everything except for password reset. When I try to reset a user password, I get the following error message:

```
 "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
```

I tried granting all permissions to the logic apps, yet I am unable to get the logic apps to work.
[API Permissions in B2C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeqS8.png)

I don't know what I am missing. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you granted the [user administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-ga#optional-grant-user-administrator-role) role?

Comment: Awesome! that solved the issue.. Thanks a lot!